# Disable SHIFT+HOME Keymap in BYOBU?

Tags: byobu

Byobu has somehow mapped the SHIFT+HOME and SHIFT+END Key combinations, which I would like to disable.

It is not in the Keymap configuration of Byobu, so I thought that it may be a back-end (screen or tmux) specific keymap, but it is mapped only in Byobu.

Is there a way to unmap those keys?

NOTE: Disabling the function-keys (e.g. via SHIFT-F12) does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that I was mistaken, and byobu is not in fault for this behavior.

In my case, the effect of pressing SHIFT+HOME/END is used for scrolling along with SHIFT+UP/DOWN keys by the terminal emulator (in my case mintty).
Disabling this functionality in mintty itself, solves the problem.

The reason why I needed the SHIFT+UP/DOWN/HOME/END functionality, is for text selecting in "tilde" text editor.
Interestingly, if tilde is called directly in the terminal (not in byobu), the SHIFT+UP/DOWN/HOME/END work as expected. But when called from byobu, it somehow reverts to the emulator default behavior.